# Secured area with locale

Tags: regex, symfony, symfony-2.3

How can I secure actions with locale - this was pretty easy in symfony1.4. I use now symfony2.3:

My security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  frontend_account_login
        security: false


    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic:
            realm: "Secured Demo Area"
        form_login:
            check_path: frontend_account_security_check
            login_path: frontend_account_login
            use_referer:        true
            default_target_path: frontend_account_hello
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: frontend_account_login            #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    #This works:
    - { path: ^/de/account/secured/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/en/account/secured/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } 
    #I want it kind of that way
    - { path: ^/{_locale}/account/secured/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I read a post with regex: ^/[a-z]+/account/secured/. But it doesn't work. Any idea how I can secure areas with locale. I found some posts here but they all don't work.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What does not exactly work? Any specific error?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I update the post.

Comment: Shouldn't you replace the `{_locale}` by a `%_locale%` or `%locale%` ?

Comment: have you tried ^/[a-z]{2}/account/secured/$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only two locales:

```yaml
- { path: ^/(en|de)/account/secured/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer of YoannCh is also correct.

Shouldn't you replace the `{_locale}` by a `%_locale%` or `%locale%`